# Expectation of derivative

Tags: probability

Let $D$ be a random variable and $a_+=max(a,0)$. Can someone give a proof of how second line is derived from the fist line?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(a) = \max(a,0) =:  [a]_{+}$ is differentiable at $a \neq 0$, with the derivative being given by $$g'(a) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $a > 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $a < 0$.}\end{cases}$$

Suppose that $z-D\neq0$ and $D-z\neq0$. Then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}[z-D]_+ = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $z-D>0$}\\ 0 & \text{if $z-D<0$} \end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial z}[D-z]_+ = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if $D-z>0$}\\ 0 & \text{if $D-z<0$} \end{cases}$$
using the chain rule. Note that $z-D>0$ iff $D<z$, and $D-z>0$ iff $D>z$. To proceed we have to assume that $\mathbb P(D = z) = 0$ for each $z$ (e.g. the distribution of $D$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure). Then $$\begin{align*}\mathbb E\left[\frac\partial{\partial z}[z-D]_+\right] &= \int \frac\partial{\partial z}[z-D]_+\,\mathrm d\mathbb P\\ &= \int_{D<z} 1\,\mathrm d\mathbb P + \int_{D>z}0\,\mathrm d\mathbb P + \int_{D=z}1\,\mathrm d\mathbb P \\ &=\int_{D\leq z} 1\,\mathrm d\mathbb P + \int_{D>z}0\,\mathrm d\mathbb P \\ &= 1\cdot\mathbb P(D\leq z) + 0\cdot\mathbb P(D>z) \\ &= \mathbb P(D\leq z),\end{align*}$$
where the first equality is the definition of expectation, the second equality uses the fact that the sets $\{D<z\},\{D>z\}$ and $\{D=z\}$ are disjoint so the integral of the above function can be computed for each set separately.  As mentioned before, the derivative is not defined for $D=z$, so we have to come up with some value in order to compute the integral. However, since, by assumption, the set has probability zero anyway, it doesn't matter what function value we assign to this set - so why not take the value 1 to get to the third last equality. The second last equality is again simply the definition of the integral. Finally, the last equality is obvious.

The other one works analogously.